# Office 365 Sharepoint Online Web Services Versus Local Sharepoint Installation

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-services

I've supported third party integrations with Sharepoint for different companies using WSDL Soap web services from the SP 2010 and 2013. This has been on their locally installed sharepoint instances.

To do this we have used the WSDL Soap web services:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154052.aspx

We use these wsdl's:

- Lists.wsdl
- SiteData.wsdl
- UserGroup.wsdl
- Webs.wsdl

Now all the rage is this Office Sharepoint online through the Office 365 portal.

I seem to be getting conflicting reports which of these features will continue to work versus stop working.

And do certain Sharepoint Online plans carry the web service features and others don't?

What quirks/gotchas are going to happen on Sharepoint Online when doing web services work that didn't happen on local installations?

Comment: SOAP web services are deprecated, so at any time, they could be removed from SPO, you'd be best suited to convert everything you can to REST.

Comment: @EricAlexander actually do you have any documentation that shows that the soap web services are deprecated?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060.aspx#DeprecatedAPIs

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my SP2010 VM open and running right now, I'll check on later, but I think Office 2010 still uses the "old" SOAP services to communicate with SharePoint (since SP2013, Word, Excel... use the new hype REST endpoints).

So, even if they're officialy deprecated, I think you're safe till Office 2010 support period ends...
But that's only a guess. Also note that SP2016 still has these SOAP interfaces.

Comment: Unless I'm missing on what you are talking about, i was asking about Sharepoint *online* soap web services availability.

Comment: This is what I'm talking about too. As Office 2010 has to be supported with SPO, and as Office 2010 uses .asmx to communicate with SharePoint, my guess is: they cannot remove these .asmx SPO-side unless they're ready to break Office 2010 while it's still supported...

Comment: OK @Evariste my trial just finished provisioning I'll start trying it out. thanks.